# ember js limit hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data and I created the following model:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  login: DS.attr('string'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('post', {
    async: true,
    inverse: null
  })
})
```

And it works perfectly when I call `api/users/1` , it returns something like this:

```
"user":{
      id: 1,
      isMine: true,
      login: 'berdof',
      posts: [1, 2, 6, 7, 8 ],
 }
```

And then it requests `api/posts/1..10` and loads each post the user have

So the question is how can I limit the `posts` relationship ?
I want to use an infinite scroll here or some kind of pagination and don't to load all 1000 posts which user can have. Is there any way of limiting this hasMany relationship or any workarounds? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you solved it? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I rebuilded my api to solve it. So instead of having hasMany posts relationship inside of a user I query for posts with api/v1/post?user=1. This way I can easily handle pagination.